# Finding dimensions of null and column space for different parameters of $t$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $t$ be a parameter and consider $$Q_t = \begin{bmatrix} 1-t & t \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ Find $\dim\big(\operatorname{Nul}(Q_t)\big)  $ and $ \dim\big(\operatorname{col}(Q_t)\big)$.

So for $\dim \operatorname{col} Q_t$ I reduced the matrix to RRE and got that  $\dim \operatorname{col} Q_t = 2$ when $t \ne 1$ and $t \ne 0$, and $1$ when $t = 0$. I wasn't really sure how to find  $\dim \operatorname{Nul}Q_t$, but it seems logical if its $1$ when $t = 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Not sure if this is correct though. Also, is there a more methodical way to find $ \dim\operatorname{Nul}Q_t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column space is spanned by the vectors $$\left\{\pmatrix{1-t \\ 1}, \pmatrix{t \\ 0} \right\}$$ which are linearly independent for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ except $t = 0$ when the second vector is equal to $\pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$.

Therefore: $$\dim \operatorname{col} Q_t = \begin{cases}
2,  & \text{if $t \ne 0$} \\
1, & \text{if $t = 0$}
\end{cases}$$

[Rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) states that $$\dim \operatorname{null} Q_t + \dim \operatorname{col} Q_t = \dim \mathbb{R^2} = 2$$

hence $$\dim \operatorname{null} Q_t =2 -\operatorname{col} Q_t = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t \ne 0$} \\
1, & \text{if $t = 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What i found strange is that to get $Q_t$ in RRE you have to multiply by $1 \over 1-t$ at some point, but $t = 1$ is not a special value by any means in this case.

Comment: @Pame Actually, you can arrive at the RRE by adding the second row multiplied by $t-1$ to the first and then swapping the rows:

$$\pmatrix{1-t & t \\ 1 & 0} \sim \pmatrix{0 & t \\ 1 & 0} \sim \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & t}$$

Notice that if $t = 1$ you are actually doing nothing in the first step, but it's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the determinant of the matrix doesn't vanish, both dimensions are $2$.   Now the determinant equals $-t$ and  in case $t=0$ both spaces share dimension one.  There's nothing special when $t=1$.

Comment: Isn't dim Nul $Q_t$ $0$ as long as there are no free variables? Is there some intuitive connection between dim Nul $Q_t$ and $det(Q_t)$?